# ui-router, component won't bind with child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

That's probably a newb question, I'm just getting started with angular/uiRouter, I'd be glad if anyone with a more experienced eye can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to bind a component with a state whose parent is abstract.

This is what I have so far:

**States**

```
    {
        name: 'main',
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'template/main.html',
        abstract: true
    }
    ,
    {
        name: 'main.data',
        resolve: {
            items: function(ItemsService){
                return ItemsService.getPosts();
            }
        },
        url:'',
        component: 'pageData'
    }
```

**Component**

```
app.component('pageData', {
templateUrl:  'template/pageData.html',
controllerAs: 'pageCtrl',
bindings: {
    items: '<'
}
```

In theory that should work but it doesn't.

So far I found that just removing the parent and accessing the state directly will work, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    {
        name: 'data',
        resolve: {
            items: function(ItemsService){
                return ItemsService.getPosts();
            }
        },
        url:'/data',
        component: 'pageData'
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your `main.html` has `<ui-view>`.

Comment: It does, the template loads, but items is undefined in page controller.

Comment: Rechecked, it doesn't. I have put the component tag(<page-data>) instead. I think you might've solved it! I'll update with results once I get to edit the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I haven't specified a `<ui-view>` for my child state in parents template, so it didn't resolve the data into component.

Found it thanks to [Shawn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861947/ui-router-component-wont-bind-with-child-state#comment67013880_39861947).